# Pass struct as id possible?

Tags: objective-c, struct

I would like to execute a function which obtains a struct in an separate Thread but not sure how to pass the struct right.

Having this:

```
- (void) workOnSomeData:(struct MyData *)data;
```

How to properly call:

```
struct MyData data = ... ;
[[[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(workOnSomeData:) object: ...
```

Using `&data` does not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While kennytm's answer is correct, there
 is a simpler way.

Use NSValue's +valueWithPointer: method to encapsulate the pointer in ani object for the purposes of spinning off the thread.  NSValue does no automatic memory management on the pointer-- it really is juste an opaque object wrapper for pointer values.

Answer (score 8):

The `object` *must be* an ObjC object. A struct is not.

You can create an ObjC to hold these info:

```
@interface MyData : NSObject {
  ...
```

or encode the struct in an NSData, assuming it *does not* contain any pointers:

```
NSData* objData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&data length:sizeof(data)];

...

-(void)workOnSomeData:(NSData*)objData {
   struct MyData* data = [objData bytes];
   ...
```

Comment: This is surely the other option but then I can use on ObjC object straight away and change my function to accept an object. I wanted to use the struct to avoid define an additional object.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the structure through void * like this.
Tested and it worked.

```
struct MyData data = ... ;

[[[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(workOnSomeData:) object:(void *)(&data)];
```